# Spark Java PCA: Java Heap Space and Missing output location for shuffle

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory, pca, executor

I try to do a PCA on a dataframe with **4.827 rows and 40.107 columns** but I take a Java heap space error and missing output location for shuffle (according to the sdterr file on executors). The error takes place during the **"treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122"** stage of PCA.

**The cluster**

It is a standalone cluster with 16 worker nodes, each one having 1 executor with 4 cores and 21.504mb memory. The master node has 15g memory which I give with "Java -jar -Xmx15g myapp.jar". Also "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" are 192 and "spark.driver.maxResultSize" is 6g.

**Simplified code**

```
df1.persist (From the Storage Tab in spark UI it says it is 3Gb)
df2=df1.groupby(col1).pivot(col2).mean(col3) (This is a df with 4.827 columns and 40.107 rows)
df2.collectFirstColumnAsList
df3=df1.groupby(col2).pivot(col1).mean(col3) (This is a df with 40.107 columns and 4.827 rows)

-----it hangs here for around 1.5 hours creating metadata for upcoming dataframe-----

df4 = (..Imputer or na.fill on df3..)
df5 = (..VectorAssembler on df4..)
(..PCA on df5 with error Missing output location for shuffle..)
df1.unpersist
```

I have seen and tried many solutions but without any result. Among them:

1. Re-partitioning the df5 or df4 to 16, 64, 192, 256, 1000, 4000 (although data do not look skewed)
2. Changing the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to 16, 64, 192, 256, 1000, 4000
3. Using 1 and 2 cores per executor so to have more memory for every task.
4. Having 2 executors with 2 cores or 4 cores.
5. Changing "spark.memory.fraction" to 0.8 and "spark.memory.storageFraction" to 0.4.

Always the same error! How is it possible to blow away all this memory?? Is it possible the df actually not fitting in memory? Please let me know if you need any other information or printscreens.

**EDIT 1**

I changed the cluster to 2 spark workers with 1 executor each with spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=48. Each executor has 115g and 8 cores. Below is the code where I load the file(2.2Gb), convert each line into a dense vector and feed the PCA.

Each row in the file has this format(4.568 rows with 40.107 double values each):

```
 "[x1,x2,x3,...]"
```

and the code:

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = sp.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/ubuntu/yolo.csv");
StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                        new StructField("intensity",new VectorUDT(),false,Metadata.empty())
            });
Dataset<Row> df = df1.map((Row originalrow) -> {
                    String yoho =originalrow.get(0).toString();
                    int sizeyoho=yoho.length();
                    String yohi = yoho.substring(1, sizeyoho-1);
                    String[] yi = yohi.split(",");
                    int s = yi.length;
                    double[] tmplist= new double[s];
                    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
                        tmplist[i]=Double.parseDouble(yi[i]);
                    }
                    
                    Row newrow = RowFactory.create(Vectors.dense(tmplist));
                    return newrow;
            }, RowEncoder.apply(schema2));
PCAModel pcaexp = new PCA()
                    .setInputCol("intensity")
                    .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
                    .setK(2)
                    .fit(df);
```

The exact error I get on the stderr of one of the 2 workers is:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 43)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferOutputStream.write(ByteBufferOutputStream.scala:41)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And this is the Stages Tab of SparkUI:

[image: stagestab]

And this is the Stage that fails(TreeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122):

[image: treeaggregate]

**EDIT 2**

[image: console]

[image: sparkstages]

**EDIT 3**

I read the whole file but taking only 10 values from each row and creating the dense vector. I still get the same error! I have a master with 235g Ram and 3 workers(1 executor each with 4 cores) and 64g Ram per executor. How could this be happening? (Not forget the total size of the file is only 2.3Gb!)

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = sp.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/ubuntu/yolo.csv");

StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                        new StructField("intensity",new VectorUDT(),false,Metadata.empty())
            });
Dataset<Row> df = df1.map((Row originalrow) -> {
                    String yoho =originalrow.get(0).toString();
                    int sizeyoho=yoho.length();
                    String yohi = yoho.substring(1, sizeyoho-1);
                    String[] yi = yohi.split(",");//this string array has all 40.107 values
                    int s = yi.length;
                    double[] tmplist= new double[s];
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){//I narrow it down to take only the first 10 values of each row
                        tmplist[i]=Double.parseDouble(yi[i]);
                    }
                    Row newrow = RowFactory.create(Vectors.dense(tmplist));
                    return newrow;
            }, RowEncoder.apply(schema2));
      
PCAModel pcaexp = new PCA()
                    .setInputCol("intensity")
                    .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
                    .setK(2)
                    .fit(df);
```

Comment: Is your dataframe sparse? such number of columns creates a very big dataset

Comment: The df4 has 192 partitions with 12-20Mb per task/partition and total 130-240Mb per executor. The weird is on the task section of df4 I noticed some executors have more partitions/tasks than others(from 8 to 23). I guess it should be 4cores x 3=12 partitions per executor. Is that normal? The df5 has also 192 partitions and if I check the first stage of PCA "rdd at PCA" it says 192 partitions with 12-20Mb per task/partition. I will also try with setting spark.memory.fraction to 0.4 and spark.memory.storageFraction to 0.6 to spill more often to disk and see what happens.

Comment: Also at the start of PCA before the error I get "WARN  org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix  - 40107 columns will require at least 12868 megabytes of memory!" But my driver has 20g memory and the executors 21g. So I would imagine that memory is not a problem. And during the treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:433 stage I see 192 partitions with 7-15Mb per task/partition.

Comment: I do not know if I am missing something, but if it sparse, how can I detect it? and how can I make not to be sparse?

Answer (score 1):

The **"Missing output location for shuffle"** occurs when your Spark application do big shuffle stages, it tries to reallocate huge amount of data among executors and there are some problems in your cluster network.

Spark says that you don´t have memory in some stage. You are doing transformations that requires different stages and they consume memory too. Besides, you persist the dataframe first, and you should check the storage level, because it is posible that you are persisting in memory.

You are chaining several Spark wide transformations: doing the first pivot stage ,for example, Spark creates a stage and performs a shuffle to group for your column and maybe you have ***data skew*** and there are executors that consume much more memory than others, and maybe the error can happen in one of them.

Besides the Dataframe transformations, the PCA estimator converts the dataframe to a RDD increasing much more the memory to calculate the covarianze matrix, and it works with dense representations of Breeze matrices of NxN elements which are **not distributed**. For example, the SVD is made with Breeze. That put a lot of pressure in one of the executors.

Maybe you can save the resulting dataframe in HDFS(or whatever) and do the PCA another Spark application.

The main problem. that you have is that before de SVD the algorithm needs to compute the Grammian Matrix and it uses a treeAggregate from RDD. This creates a very big Double matrix that will be sent to the driver, and there is the error because your driver hasn´t memory enough. You need to increase dramatically the driver memory. You have networks errors, if one executor losses the connection the job crashes it doesn´t try to re-execute.

Personally, I would try to do the PCA directly in Breeze(or Smile) in the driver, I mean, collect the RDD field because the dataset is quite smaller than the covarianze matrix and do manually with a Float representation.

Code to compute the PCA only with Breeze, neither Spark nor TreeAgregation:

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.linalg.svd._

object PCACode {
  
  def mean(v: Vector[Double]): Double = v.valuesIterator.sum / v.size

  def zeroMean(m: DenseMatrix[Double]): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val copy = m.copy
    for (c <- 0 until m.cols) {
      val col = copy(::, c)
      val colMean = mean(col)
      col -= colMean
    }
    copy
  }

  def pca(data: DenseMatrix[Double], components: Int): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val d = zeroMean(data)
    val SVD(_, _, v) = svd(d.t)
    val model = v(0 until components, ::)
    val filter = model.t * model
    filter * d
  }
  
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val df : DataFrame = ???

    /** Collect the data and do the processing. Convert string to double, etc **/
    val data: Array[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]] =
      df.rdd.map(row => (row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0))).collect()

    /** Once you have the Array, create the matrix and do the PCA **/
    val matrix = DenseMatrix(data.toSeq:_*)
    val pcaRes = pca(matrix, 2)

    println("result pca \n" + pcaRes)
  }
}
```

This code will do the PCA in the driver, check the memory. If it crashes it could be do with a Float precission.

Comment: After a lot of failed attempts I did as you said. I exported the df in csv file before pca and tried to process it with an other application just to do the pca. Only that this time I have two spark workers with 1 executor each. Each executor has 115g of Ram and 8 cores. However the error still persists.

Comment: Basically yes. I added all info in EDIT 1.

Comment: can you cast your columns to Float. The Matrix that you need to do the SVD has a size of 102GB

Comment: I am waiting for the stack trace. I can cast the tmplist[i]=Double.parseDouble(yi[i]); to tmplist[i]=Float.parseFloat(yi[i]);. But I cannot use float[] because the Vectors.dense(tmplist) accepts only double[].

Comment: I changed the tmplist[i]=Double.parseDouble(yi[i]); to tmplist[i]=Float.parseFloat(yi[i]); but still the same error. Also I have put .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp") in the spark application but I cannot find any file generated. Do I miss something?

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify what is happening

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I gave driver 120Gb Ram and 115Gb to executor, but still the same mistake. I will resize my instances and give even more memory to driver and see what happens. Could it also be related to this?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164588/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-in-rdd-collect-when-all-memory-setting-are-set-to-h). Regarding Breeze I am not sure what you mean. How can I use Breeze on the driver or even do calculations on the driver? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: The problem with your cluster still happens. Breeze is a alinear algebra library for Scala that is included in Spark. When you use Spark it performs the covarianze matrix calculation with a RDD and then it collects the result as a Dense Breeze Matrix and moves the data to the driver to do the SVD. I meant that you can do it directly in the driver collecting your initial dataset, do the covarianze matrix in the driver and the SVD using Breeze directly. If I have the time I include the code.

Comment: ok, so I re-setup my cluster with 1 master and 3 worker nodes(1 executor each). I tried with giving 235g to the master and 115g to each executor. Still the same error! How much memory would the driver need?! I would be super thankful if you had the time to write about the breeze code. However I am thinking, is there any other solution?? If not then eventually it looks like spark cannot do a pca of 40.107 features!

Comment: Also I posted a new anda bit clearer question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956751/spark-java-pca-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-on-40-107-features

Comment: Also, I tried to perform the PCA locally, on the master node(.master(local[*])) with 235g of RAM, but I still get he same error! With htop I see it going up to 201Gb and then falls to ~100Gb and later I get the error. How is that possible? There is no covariance matrix to be sent over now or?

Comment: can you add the image of the driver console with the job/stage that fails?. We can see the concrete line that crashes

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with " driver console with the job/stage that fails" but I added the console of the application where master runs locally with 235g in EDIT 2. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Also added the stage where it fails (treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122 0/4) from Spark UI.

Comment: I´ve just include the code to do the PCA with Breeze. It is in Scala, try to compile it and check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code but it seems that we still need the distributed way. I also tried to use KryoSerializer but it seems I am hitting similar error: "Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 6, required: 8 Serialization trace: data$mcD$sp (breeze.linalg.DenseVector$mcD$sp). To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value". I increased it up to 2g but nothing changed. I think I am trying to serialize an object which is more than 2Gb, which is the default maximum. Maybe the only solution is just to just take less columns than 40107.

Comment: Another option would be to create another custom PCA estimator that uses lower precision representation. Current PCA uses Breeze Double dense matrices. That could be a solution and try create the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to create a custom pca estimator or what it takes to create the issue, but yes that would be amazing if  someone could actually perform a pca on that many features.

Comment: Ok this is super weird! I made it so to take only 10 values of each row, meaning having 10 features and 4827 rows. Still I get the exact same error!! What is happening! I just posted the code in Edit 3.

Comment: I would use spark sql to do the substring with spark.sql functions. And be careful with the conversion to Array[Double], because you are creating Array[Double] of length equal to the initial features, and then you update the first 10 positions but the array is of the same size so the Vector representation is the same size.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It seems that eventually the problem is not with PCA but with the "double[] tmplist = new double[40107]". It is very big for java to create and use. I wish there was an other way to use that array because spark dense vector take only double[].

Comment: java can create Arrays of 40107 lenght, there is no problem with that. The problem is with the treeAgregate that moves the cov matrix to the driver. a 16 Exp 8 double positions

Comment: ok, maybe that is why even if I use the Vector assembler(without manually assembling the vectors and creating double[40107]) spark still fails with the same error "ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)". This means basically that spark cannot handle 40107 columns in pca.

Comment: The point is that my driver has 235g and the 3 executors 115g each. So how much memory would it take to move the cov matrix to the driver for that specific data?

Comment: or maybe more accurate question is how big is the covariance matrix? The data are 40107 features with 4827 rows.